# Using a memory location string in C++

Tags: c++, pointers, widget

I'm not sure what you call this but what I am trying to do is firstly record the memory address of three widgets of the same type instantiated at different times.

To identify each widget I want to use the memory locations I have recorded for each instance e.g., 0x....... etc. to find the widget again and identify characteristics of that widget.

I just don't know how to use a memory location and refer to that memory location by allocating it to a pointer?  Would anyone know how to do this?

I record the memory locations in a vector  of int.

```
vector<int> myvector;

// to show that I have recorded three memory addresses I print them out as integers.

for(int i = 0; i < myvector.size(); i++)
{
    cout << myvector[i] <<endl;
}

// then I want to use their location to identify characteristics of each widget.  

for(int i = 0; i < myvector.size(); i++)
{
    Widget_Type *tpe = myvector[i];

    // now identify the x and y value of each widget.
    cout << "x value is: " << tpe->x() << endl;
    cout << "y value is: " << tpe->y() << endl;

    //thats it?
}
```

Comment: You can't use `int` to store memory addresses (pointers)! Use a *pointer* to store a pointer.

Comment: Thanks, but that's not the question ;)  In this case I have no choice. I specifically need to know how to use that memory location string?

Comment: Then think about this: The type `int` is usually still four bytes on 64-bit platforms, where pointers are *eight* bytes. How would you store an eight-byte pointer in a four-byte type?

Comment: Well, let's say I don't use an int.  That was my approach?  What else can I record the address as? Can the int be converted to something I can use in the context that I want to use it?  Is there any feasible way of going about this with or without integers?

Answer (score 2):

As already pointed out in the comments, it is a bad idea to store pointers as integer variables.

Simply use `WidgetType*` as the vectors value type.

Your code would look like this then:

```
// use WidgetType* instead of int
vector<WidgetType*> myvector;

// print out the pointer values == memory addresses of the pointer
for(int i = 0; i < myvector.size(); i++)
{
  cout << myvector[i] <<endl;
}

// access your widgets with your stored pointers
for(int i = 0; i < myvector.size(); i++)
{
  cout << "x value is: " << myvector[i]->x() << endl;
  cout << "y value is: " << myvector[i]->y() << endl;
}
//that's it
```